# whether $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ vector function or scalar?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I have read about functions when the functions are from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then functions are scalar and when functions are from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ then functions are vector functions so what about $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ if anyone could tell me. I will remain grateful.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can view a function as either assigning points in its codomain to points in its domain, or alternatively as parametrizing an image of its domain inside its codomain. This leads to alternate descriptions of functions $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as either $n$-dimensional vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^m,$ or parametrized $m$-dimensional submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Here are some common names for these views of functions for low values of $m$ and $n$.

- $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

  - Functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are called **single variable real functions.** Its derivative is the slope function, and its antiderivative is the area under the curve.
  - Or a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be viewed as a **parametrized 1-dimensional displacement curve** (eg the position of a car on a road as a function of time). Its derivative is speed, and its antiderivative is position or net displacement.
- $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R},$ especially with $n=2,3.$

  - These are **(multivariable) real scalar functions** or **scalar fields**. Its derivative is the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) $\nabla f.$ For antiderivatives, with $n=2,3$ you could take the [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) $\int f(x)\,ds$ along a curve. For $n=2$ you can also compute the double integral over a 2D region $\iint f(x)\,dA.$ For $n=3$, you have the [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral) $\iint f(x)\,dS$, and also the triple integral $\iiint f(x)\,dV$ over a 3D region. And higher dimensional analogues too if $n>3.$
- $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n,$ especially with $n=2,3.$

  - One could perhaps view a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector field assigning an $n$ dimensional vector to every point of the line.
  - Better to view these as **parametrized curves** in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Its derivative is a tangent vector. This can serve as the domain of a line integral $\int f(x)\,ds$ of a scalar function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n,$ or for the path integral $\int \mathbf{F}(x)\cdot\,d\mathbf{r}$ of a vector field $\mathbf{F}\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n.$
- $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$

  - A **vector field** in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Two different kinds of derivatives are considered, the [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}$ and the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) $\nabla\times \mathbf{F}.$ For integrals you have the path integral $\int \mathbf{F}(x)\cdot\,d\mathbf{r}$ along a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the flux integral $\int\mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{n}d\mathbf{s}$.
  - A transformation of a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (like a change from Cartesian to polar coordinates). Its derivative is a [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).
- $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$

  - A **vector field** in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Two different kinds of derivatives are considered, the [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}$ and the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) $\nabla\times \mathbf{F}.$ For integrals you have the path integral $\int \mathbf{F}(x)\cdot\,d\mathbf{r}$, and the flux integral $\iint\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$.
  - A transformation of a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (like a change from Cartesian to spherical coordinates). Its derivative is a [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).
- $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$

  - Perhaps $3$ dimensional vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$
  - A parametrized surface in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Its derivative is two independent tangent vectors. This can be the domain of a surface integral $\iint f(x)\,dS$ of a scalar function $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, or a flux integral $\iint\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$ of a vector field $\mathbf{F}\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3.$

The latter view, of functions assigning mapping points in the domain into points in the codomain, is quite general and will serve well to think of maps between more abstract spaces no matter their dimension. The former point of view, where to each point in the domain we assign a point living in the codomain, generalizes instead to sections of bundles.

Of course, in our cases above, the distinction is just a point of view: vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and functions $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ are literally the same thing. A parametrized surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a 3-component vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the same thing.

Comment: And it is pretty customary to call functions $\;\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;n\ge2\;$ as "scalar functions" .

Comment: @DonAntonio good point. let me add the term.